# Windows Phone 8 - Beacon connection

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to make an app for WP 8 that recognize Bluetooth beacons (BLE) and I want to do this in a native app, does anyone has experience on this or can suggest an basic implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/201027523-Which-devices-are-compatible-with-Estimote-Beacons-) i see it supports only for `WindowsPhone 8.1` platform and yet the tools to develop are to be out.

For more you could check out the `Channel9` [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-519) about the new `Bluetooth` APIs.